# Upload a file to Drupal server from an outside URL

Tags: 7, files

I am trying to cache in the server the profile images provided by the Facebook Graph API. 
So far what I did unsuccessfully was getting the path of the image then calling:

```
$file = file_save_upload($big_pic_url, array(), $dest, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
```

This returns `NULL` every time. I tried several syntax for the destination path, and also for the Pic URL path, nothing seems to work.

I am doing this the right way? Can `file_save_upload()` take an external link as part of its argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution I've used recently for a Facebook module. Set the image path to `$path` variable (ie. http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture). Then do the following to store it via Drupal's managed file system:

```
$image = file_get_contents($path); // this is a PHP function to get a string representation of the image file

$destination = 'public://path/to/store/this/image/name.jpg'; // a stream wrapper path where you want this image to reside on your file system including the desired filename

$file = file_save_data($image, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

if (is_object($file)) { // if you get back a Drupal $file object, everything went as expected so make the status permenant
   $file->status = 1;
   $file = file_save($file);
}
```

Comment: It works if `file_get_contents()` accept a URL; in some PHP installations, file functions are not allowed to use a URL as filename.

Comment: Yes you're exactly right about that. I have no idea how to do it otherwise... sorry!

Comment: You can use others options like `fopen()` or `curl` [Reading a Remote File Using PHP](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx)

Comment: Ok thanks Matt, file_get_content works form the server so that will do perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function I am using and that works.

```
function get_external_image($url) { 
    $external_image = file_get_contents($url);
    $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
    $name_dest = rand(1000,9999)."_". basename($parsed_url["path"]);
    $file = file_save_data($external_image, 'public://'.$name_dest , FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    if (is_object($file) && file_exists($file->uri)) {
        $file->status = 1;
        $file = file_save($file);
        drupal_write_record('file_usage', $file);
        return (array) $file;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is an example on how to use it.

```
// Load your node.
$node = node_load("9999");
// Assign your image.
$node->field_image[$node->language]['0'] = get_external_image("http://cdn.sstatic.net/drupal/img/logo.png");
// Save your node.
node_save($node);
```